# CakePHP проблемы с пагинацией

Tags: php, mvc, framework, pagination, cakephp

Первый раз работаю с `CakePHP`. Возникла проблема
На странице категории (http://nbags.ru/catalog/zhenschinam) есть пагинатор. 
Я установил ему следующие опции:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs))
```

У меня получаются ссылки вида - `/catalog/zhenschinamzhenschinam?page=2`
Мне же нужно - `/catalog/zhenschinam?page=2`

Почему дублируется категория,если `$this->passedArgs` содержит "zhenschinam"?

Comment: если ваша текущая url `/catalog/zhenschinam` то `?page=2` создастся вообще без всяких опций, что у вас в `$passedArgs` и зачем вы его передаете? Если для передачи фильтра  бренда и сортировки, то и тут пагинатор должен сам все подхватить (речь ведь про `Cake 3.x` ?)

Comment: опции пагинатора вообще [вот здесь описаны](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#configuring-pagination-options)